# print arraylist without brackets

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my output to be displayed without the brackets. I feel like it's a simple thing but just can't figure it out.

The output looks like this

```
22 ([1, 2, 11]) 
33 ([1, 3, 11]) 
44 ([1, 2, 4, 11, 22]) 
55 ([1, 5, 11]) 
66 ([1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 33]) 
77 ([1, 7, 11])
```

But I want it to have no brackets displayed so it looks like this

```
22 (1, 2, 11) 
33 (1, 3, 11) 
44 (1, 2, 4, 11, 22) 
55 (1, 5, 11) 
66 (1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 33) 
77 (1, 7, 11)
```

Here's a piece of my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int e = 0;
        // palindromic composite number
        int drome = 0;
        // starting int range
        int start = 10;
        // ending int range
        int end = 10000;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
            if (isPalindromic(i)) {
                drome = i;
                if (!isPrime(i))
                    System.out.println(drome + " (" + getDivisors(drome) + ")");
            }
        }
    }

    // gets gets the divsors and adds them to arraylist if divsor is a
    // palindrome
    public static ArrayList getDivisors(int number) {
        ArrayList numbersDivisor = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0 && i != number && isPalindromic(i)) {
                numbersDivisor.add(i);
            }
        }
        return numbersDivisor;
    }
```

Comment: Store the resultant `ArrayList` in a variable. Store the result from calling `toString` in another `String`. Trim the parenthesis from this `String` and use it to print it.

Comment: A simple hack would be to replace all `[` and `]` characters with `""` using [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).  `getDivisors(drome).toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","");`  But this works only because your data structure doesn't include any `String`s that might contain real square-bracket characters.  It's not a completely general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `StringBuilder` instead:

```
public static StringBuilder getDivisors(int number) {
    StringBuilder numbersDivisor = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number && isPalindromic(i)) {
            numbersDivisor.append(i).append(',');
        }
    }
    if(0 < (i = numbersDivisor.length())) {
        numbersDivisor.deleteCharAt(i - 1);//remove that last comma
    }
    return numbersDivisor;
}
```

OR

You may replace the brackets instead in the main():

```
String divs = getDivisors(drome).toString().replace("\\[", "(").replace("\\]", ")");
System.out.println(drome + divs);
```

OR

You may try the suggestion given by @LuiggiMendoza.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is probably to modify your method to return a `String` like,

```
public static String getDivisors(int number) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number && isPalindromic(i)) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(i);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite the result of the implicit `toString` from `List` (please program to the interface and please don't use raw types) like

```
public static List<Integer> getDivisors(int number) {
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number && isPalindromic(i)) {
            al.add(i);
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

And then
    if (!isPrime(i)) {
        String str = getDivisors(drome).toString();
        str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(drome + " (" + str + ")");
    }

Comment: You can't simply assign a `List<Integer>` to a `String` variable. You'd need to do: `String str = getDivisors(drome).toString();`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` method uses the `toString()`method (deep inside) to get things printed for any objects passed as parameters. 
`ArrayList` class inherits `AbstractList` which inherits `AbstractCollection` class which has `java.lang.Object`  class's `toString()` method overridden. Following is the default implementation of toString() method in `AbstractCollection` class:

```
 public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = i.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! i.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Create a new class which inherits the `ArrayList` class, and overrides the`toString()` method. Read the inline comment with the code:

```
public class BracketlessArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

 /**
 * For serialization.. ignore this
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String toString() {
             Iterator<E> i = iterator();
            if (! i.hasNext()){
                //return "[]";  //line removed to avoid square brackets
                 return "";
            }


             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             //sb.append('[');  //line removed to avoid square brackets
             for (;;) {
                 E e = i.next();
               sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
                 if (! i.hasNext()){
                     //line removed to avoid square brackets
                     //return sb.append(']').toString();  
                     return sb.toString();                         
                 }

                 sb.append(", ");
             }
         }
}
```

Now modify your `getDivisors()` method this way:

```
public static BracketlessArrayList getDivisors(int number) {
    BracketlessArrayList numbersDivisor = new BracketlessArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number && isPalindromic(i)) {
            numbersDivisor.add(i);
        }
    }
    return numbersDivisor;
}
```

That'll do the job for you the right way.